Saving R tempfiles into a zip with desired names
I generate files within my shiny app and save then in tempfiles later to be downloaded within a zip.
However, naming the files within the zip is not so obvious.
I spent over an hour with ChatGPT trying to solve the issue, no success.
See example
library(zip)

filex <- 'file.csv'
file <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
write.csv(mtcars, file)

zip_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
zip::zipr(zip_file, files = file)
print(utils::unzip(zip_file, list = TRUE))

The content of the zipfile will look similar to file2d24470d428d.csv
I tried without success to create a named vector
file2 <- file
names(file2) = filex
zip::zipr(zip_file, files = file2)
print(utils::unzip(zip_file, list = TRUE))

file3 <- filex
names(file3) = file
zip::zipr(zip_file, files = file3)
print(utils::unzip(zip_file, list = TRUE))


Both solutions don't work.
The main issue is that all these files only exist within the Shiny and tempfiles, I cannot save them elsewhere, rename, etc.
I looked for different packages (archive, sf). But again, no success.
Any idea on how to solve this?

It's more about tempfile(), generating unique file names is its intended behaviour. For your use case you might want to consider file.path(tempdir(), ...) to create files to tempdir :
library(zip)

filex <- 'file.csv'
file <- file.path(tempdir(), filex)
file
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\m\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp4Gfo3K/file.csv"
write.csv(mtcars, file)

zip_file <- zip(tempfile(fileext = ".zip"), files = file, mode = "cherry-pick")
zip_file
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\m\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmp4Gfo3K\\file478c4cf4302.zip"
zip_list(zip_file)
#>   filename compressed_size uncompressed_size           timestamp permissions
#> 1 file.csv             865              1816 2024-07-27 08:22:44         600
#>      crc32 offset
#> 1 742a8e58      0

Created on 2024-07-27 with reprex v2.1.0

Creating named files directly in tempdir() is unsafe, because you can’t always avoid collisions that way. Create a nested directory using tempfile() in combination with unlink() and dir.create(), and create your named files inside that.

Actually rather than unlink()ing the file it would be even safer to create a nested directory whose name is derived from a tempfile(), to avoid collisions via filesystem race conditions: dir = paste0(tempfile(), ".dir") dir.create(dir) is about as safe as it gets.
